# python3, Trying to get an output from my function I defined, need some guidance

Tags: python-3.x

I found pretty cool ASN API tool that allows me to supply an AS # and it will go out and pull down the subnets that relate with that ASN.

Here is (rough) but partial code. I am defining a function ASNNUMBER (to which I will supply the number through another file)

When I call url here, it just gives me an n...

What I'm trying to do here, is append my str(ASNNUMBER) to the end of the ?q= parameter in the URL.

Once I do that, I'd like to display my results and output it to a file

```
import requests

def asnfinder(ASNNUMBER):
    print('n\n######## Running ASNFinder ########\n')
    url = 'https://api.hackertarget.com/aslookup?q=' + str(ASNNUMBER)
    response = requests.get(url)
```

My results I'd like to get is an output of the get request I'm performing

## Running ASNFinder

n

Comment: That `n` can be from a typo in the `print()` call. How do you call the function?

Comment: What is ASNNUMBER here? What type it have?

Comment: @Andellys it is a string I supply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write something like that:

```
import requests

def asnfinder(ASNNUMBER):
    print('n\n######## Running ASNFinder ########\n')
    url = 'https://api.hackertarget.com/aslookup?q=' + str(ASNNUMBER)
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.text
    print(data)

    with open('filename', 'r') as f:
        f.write(data)
```

It must works fine

P.S. If it helped ya, please make sure you mark this as the answer :)